# Can we establish $f_0: X_0\to Y_0$ for given $f:X_0\times \operatorname {Spec}k\to Y_0\times \operatorname {Spec} k$ by taking finite extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $K/k_0$ be infinite field extension, and $X_0, Y_0$ be finite type schemes over $k_0$.

Now base change $X:=X_0\times_{k_0} \operatorname {Spec}K, Y:=Y_0\times _{k_0} \operatorname {Spec} K$, and
$f: X\to Y$ is morphism over $K$.

> Now is there intermediate field　$k_0\subset k_1\subset k$ such that $k_1/k_0$ is finite, and
> morphism $f_1: X_0\times_{k_0}\operatorname {Spec} k_1\to X_0\times_{k_0}\operatorname {Spec} k_1$ over $k_1$ such that
> $f_1\times_{k_1}k=f$?

If you need, you can assume various condition s.t. $k$ is algebraically closed, $k_0$ is finite field, or $X_0, Y_0$ is integral.

Comment: Purely transcendental extensions need to be ruled out. Also, might "wild automorphisms" be a problem in the case $X_0=Y_0=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q)$ and $K=\mathbb C$?

Comment: The correct statement is that you can find a *finitely generated* extension $k_1$. Something like the argument following the word "recipe" [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364238/on-a-quasi-separated-assumption-in-a-lemma-for-the-homotopy-exact-sequence-of-th) should be enough to get you a solution: figure out how to write things down so that your map can be specified by finitely many elements of $K$, and then take $k_1$ to be $k$ adjoin those elements. To check fg is the best you can do, consider $X=Y=\Bbb A^1$ and the constant map to a transcendental point.